# Can't resolve sites with Windows 2008 R2 DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I have recently added a Windows 2008 R2 AD controller and DNS to my home network. However, I have a problem resolving some of the sites.

If I don't use my home DNS, everything's fine.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Thanks guys, I googled up on how to setup "forward requests to another DNS". That fixed it. I am forwarding them to google public DNS. Is that a good dns? Edit, I am in sydney area.

Comment: Google DNS servers works very well. I never had any problem with those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your home DNS should be set to forward requests to another DNS (usually your ISP or your router).  We could do a better job of assisting if you could give us more detail on what works and what doesnt as well as how you have it configured.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information about DNS configuration. Did You check does server listen on right network adapter?? Check forwarders and ROOT hints... Use nslookup utility from servers command line to check does server resolves external namespace... Like I said, You must provide more information.